# Get itunes link for whole account before submitting an app

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, itunes

I know how to get a link to the app before you publish it, but is there a way to get a link to the entire profile before you submit any app? Link like this one: 
https://itunes.apple.com/us/developer/google-inc./id281956209

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to get Developer ID. And to get Developer Id you need to simply try this steps:

- Open your any of the app on browser
- You will find "View more by this developer" option on top left side. Just click on that
- So it will open up all your apps. Now just check URL in browser top you will see ID in URL. That is the developer ID that you can use.

**For example:**

https://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/felipe-tumonis/id318226300?mt=8

Here 318226300 is that Id through which we can link to entire profile.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks, buy i asked about a moment you don't have any app published on AppStore yet